# how to upgrade setup already installed in install shield

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I have one question.I have already installed my set up in another PC (say PC-Shiva) and then I updated my project.Now I want that my modified changes should reflect in to set up which is already installed in PC-Shiva.

I used it by adding new "upgrade path" in install shield steps but didn't achieved.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please add more details? What exactly you added? What was not updated - files, registry? What type of installation?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have changed the logic in code then I build my project and build my set up now I want to provide automatic updation to existing installed set up.

Comment: Please refer to this documentation (http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/Upgrades.htm) to properly create upgrade item.

Comment: Thanks for reply...Go to Upgrade path..select msi file (msi file is installer package)...path is Express\DVD-5\DiskImages\DISK1
 
then change version and in "General Information" change version and product code ....
Don't change upgrade code 
then build set up and install set up again...it will not install set up again will only reflect the changes only.